MIME error when routing through Azure App Gateway and custom nginx conf
I have two react apps hosted on two different azure web apps fronted by an azure application gateway with a path-based routing rule (one rule with 2 paths - "/" and "/members") as below:
FancyDomain.com ------------> App gateway ------ "/" ------> Webapp1
FancyDomain.com/members ----> App gateway -- "/members" ---> Webapp2
I use the same domain name, say "FancyDomain.com". The goal is to route requests from "FancyDomain.com" to "webapp1" and "FancyDomain.com/members" to "webapp2". These two webapps are in two different backend pools with http settings to override path as “/“.
When I access the individual webapps' default hostnames (webapp1.azurewebsites.net), they work as expected. However, when I try accessing "FancyDomain.com/members", I get the below error
"Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."
But, my healthcheck works though "FancyDomain.com/members/health/ready" (returns "200 healthy" as expected"). So, I am starting to think that it is because of the custom nginx conf that I have.
** Webapp2 - nginx.conf (/members)**
server {
    listen 3000;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /healthcheck {
        return 200 'Healthy';
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

**Webapp1 config ("/") **
server { location / { root /usr/share/nginx/html; }

 location /health/ready { return 200 'Healthy'; add_header Content-Type text/plain; } }

Both have their own dockerfiles and containerized and deployed independently in two different azure webapps.
Please advise if anyone has any idea of what is going on here? Thanks.
